# Is there a way to hide the "format" command from the contextual menu in Explorer?

Tags: windows, format

When one right-clicks on a drive in Explorer, the "Format" and "Eject" command are one next to the other. This is mildly disturbing, since Eject is very commonly used and Format is much rarer and much more drastic in its consequences. The issue is compounded when using a touchpad instead of a mouse.

Is there a way to change the order of the commands or to hide the "dangerous" one?